# Tools to view code coverage results of MSTest in Jenkins

Tags: mstest, code-coverage, jenkins

Are there any tools available to see the MSTest code coverage results in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to an XSLT that can transform the XML into some nice HTML:

http://dbebek.wordpress.com/continuous-integration/xslt-for-mstest-code-coverage/

Comment: This blog seems to have been deleted by it's author